# Which React navigation action to use to unmount

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a react native app with two screens (actually too many): `ScreenA` and `ScreenB`. In `ScreenA`, I am doing some API calls and in `ScreenB`, I have some animation. I am using stack navigator to visit `ScreenB` from `ScreenA`. In `ScreenB`, I have some animation in my `useEffect()` hook and also from gestures. When I move away from `ScreenB` to `ScreenA` and then back to `ScreenB`, the state of the screen is not changed. It remains the same. I want the entire animation to reset, the useEffect() to be called again, but only for `ScreenB`. I want all my other mounted screens to be mounted, to avoid calling APIs and displaying data again but `ScreenB` to reset to its initial state if I move away from it. How can I achieve this in most efficient way possible? Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide your code? The useEffect is especially important. What is inside its dependency array?

Comment: I have loads of shared values and dependent values from reanimated in my useEffect(), these values are changed in the start, and animate for some time, or are changed with gestures such as scroll and tap.

Answer (score 0):

You could  use [useIsFocused](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/) in a useEffect and reset the animation with something like

```js
const isFocused = useIsFocused();
useEffect(()=>{
  if(isFocused){
    // start your animations
  }
  else{
    // stop your animations
  }
},[isFocused])
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I reset everything to its original state without explicitly changing the value of each variable?

Comment: You could call `cancelAnimation` in the else block, and start the animations in the if. I don't know if thats what you are looking for